# How to enable copy / cut / paste functions when using iframe execCommand in firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, rich-text-editor

The copy/cut/paste for `iframe` `execCommand` functions are not enabled by default in Firefox. How do I enable them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this might help a little,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla

http://www-archive.mozilla.org/editor/

Comment: Thanks. The reference was of use.

Comment: Glad I could help in some way :)